# read datalayer for multiple items in GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager

in GTM, when I make DLV & define its key, some platforms put numbers in the arrays of products that indicate to every item for events like purchase that maybe done with buying multiple products,
for example, if I add 3 products to cart then go to buy , the purchase event will contain 3 arrays for 3 products the first will take array no. 0, the second will take no. 1 and the last will take no. 2 like image below
If I define the key without numbers won't read any data and if I define with certine no. will read data of one product only (as in the second image below)
How can I define the variable to read all items data not one item only?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhdRL.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFh6X.jpg)

I hope know how I can read the data for all items to purchase event

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.